# Multiple TV displays on a PC, each with their own desktop

Tags: tv, multiple-monitors

I want to hook up two TVs to a computer, with each having their own display/desktop, analogous to a dual-screen setup but with TVs (taking S-video inputs) instead of monitors. How do I do this? Can I get a card that has multiple S-video outputs?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a graphics card that supports two outputs (most modern cards do), then just find adapters from whatever the output connectors are, to S-Video (e.g. two VGA → S-Video adapters).

[image]